# CakePHP: saving information in session

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables, cakephp-2.1

I am writing my own Auth component for CakePHP 2, which inherit from BaseAuthenticate. This component use an external lib (located in /usr/share/php) which save information in the $_SESSION variable.
My problem is that when I change of page, all this information is removed from $_SESSION, so the external lib do not sees that I am already connected.

I tried to save the content of $_SESSION added by the lib by using $this->Session->write in Auth.MyAuthenticateComponent, but this is also removed.

Thanks for your help.

edit :

The code :

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $use = array('User');
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Sheets', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Arise');
    }
}

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Arise');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
           if ($this->Auth->login())
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            else
                $this->Session->setFlash('Error');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}

App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
require_once('/usr/share/php/openid/consumer/consumer.php');

class AriseAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    protected function _ariseAuthenticate($openid_url)
    {
        $consumer =& AriseOpenID::getInstance();
        $required = array(
            'http://somewhere/types/identifiant',
            'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
            'http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly'
        );

        $consumer->setReturnTo('http://mysite/users/login');
        $consumer->setTrustRoot('http://mysite/users/login');
        $consumer->authenticate($openid_url, $required);

        if ($consumer->isLogged()) {
            $first_name = $consumer->getSingle('http://axschema.org/namePerson/first');
            $nick = $consumer->getSingle('http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly');
            $id_arise = $consumer->getSingle('http://openid.iiens.net/types/identifiant');

            return array(
                'id_arise' => $id_arise,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'nick' => $nick
            );
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function checkUser($result)
    {
        $User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
        $result = $User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id_arise' => $result['id_arise']
            )
        ));

        if (!$result) {
            $User->create();
            $User->save(array(
                'id_arise' => $result['id_arise'],
                'first_name' => $result['first_name'],
                'nick' => $result['nick']
            ));

            $result = $User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id_arise' => $result['id_arise']
                )
            ));
        }

        $user = $result['User'];
        unset($result['User']);

        return array_merge($user, $result);
    }

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)        
    {
        if (!$request->is('post'))
            return false;

        $openid_url = (array_key_exists('login', $request->data))
            ? $request->data['login']['openid_url']
            : NULL;

        $openid_url = ($openid_url == '') ? NULL : $openid_url;

        if ($result = $this->_ariseAuthenticate($openid_url))
            return $this->checkUser($result);

        return false;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($result = $this->_ariseAuthenticate(NULL))
            return $this->checkUser($result);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a `session_start()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, the external lib tries to get the session id with session_id(), and if this value is empty it executes session_start() (this is never the case).

Comment: Show code and what's the external lib?

Comment: I have added the code to my first post. The external lib is an OpenID lib adapted to one particular consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unit testing your auth adapter? It is hard to tell what is wrong but I'm more or less sure authenticate() does not return the array but always false? Because if authenticate() returns valid user data it would be written to the session.

See http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-AuthComponent.html#543, that calls http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-AuthComponent.html#690 which calls all configured auth adapters. If your adapter returns an user array it should work. So I assume your adapter fails to return the array.